# Strengths and weaknesses of Thresh

Tags: league-of-legends

What are the strengths of Thresh’s kit, and what are his weaknesses? What matchups is he strong and weak going into?

Answer (score 2):

Strengths:

Over all thresh excels at long range hooking of enemy champs

Due to how long his *stun* time when he hits and the range of his Q he can output a long range of danger

His w the lantern can be thrown out to grant a shield to the first ally champion in range but more importantly it allows an ally to fling themselves to thresh's location allowing for hard punishment of enemies that thresh hooks

Additionally thresh has a passive that allows him to get armor and ability power for free - meaning he can become tanky easily

---

Weaknesses:

His Greatest weakness however is how slow his Q hook is (both windup animation and travel time animation) and additionally his hook stops and hooks the first target hit meaning he must bypass minions to land a hook on an enemy champ

Comment: His lantern has a bit of a cast time, making clutch shields a bit harder to pull off. That said, if you can see a gank coming, he can easily help teammates out of sticky situations with his lantern.

Comment: @Shelby115 that and you can also create a gank with it if you see a jng coming in

Answer (score 2):

Thresh has a lot of neat little interactions and mechanics that make mastering him really valuable.

- Thresh can flay enemy champions out of most non-ultimate dashes (ex. Leona, Lee sin, Zac...ect) if you time it well. You can also hook people out of dashes but it's a lot harder.
- You can use Thresh's lantern to minion block people by placing the lantern between the turrets in top/bot lane and the wall, so instead of walking through the narrow gap, their character walks around the turret.
- Not entirely sure if this still works, but Lee Sin used to be able to w dash to a thresh lantern and then take it to cover insane distance.
- If you hit level 2 before your opponents, you have a strong cheese with flash, flay, hook ignite.

Thresh is also good for level 1 jungle invades, turret dives where he can lantern the jungler out of the turret, and defending against poorly executed dives, since he has really good single target cc.

However playing against competent Morganas is tough and competent poke lanes (q max Soraka, Brand...ect) can also be really hard if you can't find hooks through minions. In general, if you have a high lane pressure adc like Draven or Caitlyn, you can easily zone your opponents from the wave. However, if your 2v2 is weak the only hooks you will realistically land are going to have to be through the minion wave.

In general Thresh is pretty strong right now (preseason 9) and probably will be until/if the meta shifts in season 9.

Comment: "right now" is relative. What patch or update is this from?